# Add a days after current date in Django models by taking user defined days by creating separate variable

Tags: datetime, django-models, integer, timedelta, days

I want to create bill via Django. **I want to add 10 days after current date**. But days should be user defined. ***if due_days= 10 then it will be get added after current due_date***
I tried this

```
from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

due_days = models.IntegerField()
due_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=due_days))
```

Error:

```
due_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=due_days))
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: IntegerField
```

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach by overriding `save()` method. I think it's the only thing you can do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.due_days:
        self.due_date = datetime.now()+timedelta(days=self.due_days)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what instance should be. because its giving error on TypeError: calculate_due_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Comment: I guess it does not work in new Django, I change my answer with another solution @ShwetaShinde

Comment: Its working but due_date field is getting deleted. due_date field is not showable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.due_days:
        self.due_date = datetime.now()+timedelta(days=self.due_days)
        print ("due_date",self.due_date)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Its giving me correct output when I add no of days in current date. But due_date field not getting saved in database. and its not showable.

How can I saved it to database?